# Responsive on desktop, unresponsive on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Launched a website yesterday, thought everything was finished, but then I went to view the website on a mobile, it isn't being responsive, yet on the desktop it is fully responsive. I've used media queries a number of times and previous websites have all been responsive. On one phone it will be be responsive, but things like the jQuery menu, titles and links are small, but the paragraphs are the size I have set them too. Yet on another phone, it is completely unresponsive. Before uploading any code, does anyone know a possible problem? Are vendor prefixes needed?

Comment: Can't read your mind dude, sorry. Gotta give us more than just "it doesn't work".

Comment: Why would you say "before uploading any code"? Why not just give the URL to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the site, but I had a similar problem which was fixed by including a meta viewport in the page head.

Something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: not sure why this got a downvote? without seeing code this would be my first thought too!

Comment: didn't downvote, but answering a question on a "whim" isn't advised (IMO). that's what comments are for.

Comment: Yes!! Can't believe I missed that out. Thank you!!

Comment: If that fixed it, could you mark the answer as accepted?
@RobScott - ordinarily I would agree but this question seemed to particularly ask for "whim" solutions